# TypeError thrown, but function still runs, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

My console throws an uncaught typeError because it doesn't know what `jQuery` is yet, but then proceeds to execute the load, and load in the content, and then I get the `load complete` message.

I have the following code:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#content-loader').load('someFile.html', function() {
        console.log('load complete');
    });
})();
```

Why is that happening, and how can I get rid of the error and load in the html file?

As of now, `someFile.html` only contains text, no scripts.

Error Screen Cap:
[image]

### Attempted Solution

```
(function($){
  ...code...
})(jQuery);
```

Gets rid of the error, but does not load the html file

Comment: Are you sure that's whats causing the error? Can you post the error msg?

Comment: yup. It tells me `jQuery(..) is not a function` and shows me the line

Comment: it still happens if you replace jquery with $?

Comment: Thats what I had it as on the outset, and thought maybe using `jQuery` would get rid of the error

Comment: It could be coming from a script in `'someFile.html'` which happens to have the same line number...?

Comment: @Adjit sorry for asking, but does the error line indicated in console matches with this code file line?

Comment: You will have to post everything in the code so we can find out what's going on...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan no scripts in the file, just text for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically calling `jQuery(func)();`. Passing a function to jquery might return a jquery object but not a function you can call with those last `()`. Your error message exactly: `jQuery(..) is not a function` because it's the return of a jQuery call, a jQuery object, not a function.

Try to use:

```
(function($){
  ...code...
})(jQuery);
```

Which is: Call this anonymous function that has parameter `$` passing `jQuery` to it.
That is a pattern a lot of people use.

Another quick (and weird) solution would be to remove your last `()` and the `$` parameter from your wrapper.

Comment: So, the logic behind the error makes a little more sense now, however, by making this change, the content does not load. Let me try your most recent suggestion.

Comment: No didn't throw any errors. So I changed it to `$(function(){...})` getting rid of the function call `()` and that seems to work

Comment: @Adjit It's because it was the same as you have now, but **after** the evaluation of your function it tried to use the return of the jquery call as a function...

Comment: @Adjit First, the function passed as a parameter to jQuery() is bound to the `onready` event, then the object returned from the jQuery() function is being executed (which throws an error), then when the document is ready, the content of the callback function is run (which logs 'load complete').